# Is it possible to build Angular code on an old computer

Tags: angular, resources

I have an old computer having AMD Athlon 64 bit running Lubuntu 18.04.
I have 1 GB RAM on this computer.

Is it possible to build and run Angular 9 code base on this computer?

I tried building the code but it seems to go on for hours together(2 hrs and more) and fail.

Please let me know if you have a solution.

Thanks,
Srinivasa Pradeep

Comment: What exactly "fails"? What is the output in the console when you try to build your project?

Comment: @MikeS. I tried to reproduce so that I can provide the exact reason for failure, ran ng build and it ran for over 2 hours. Got fed up and terminated the build. I later realised and tried to check if the prod build will be any better. So ran ng build --prod=true. That surprisingly completed in around 10 minutes. Am wondering to use the prod build itself

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the normal build was taking very long time and probably may not complete.

I then tried by giving the --prod switch to indicate production build like:
ng build --prod=true

Then the build completed in around 20 minutes.

I am now building the production build itself on the Lubuntu box

Thanks for help